How can I scrape a dynamically rendered webpage using Selenium?
This is the page I'm trying to scrape. My goal is to check whether or not the string "Any available Pool will appear here." is on the page.
I've done some research and found out that the page is dynamically generated by a script in the html which contains all the content of the website in a dictionary-like data structure.
The issue I'm running into is that, even after loading the page and scrolling down, the page source that I'm extracting with (driver.getPageSource()) still doesn't contain the html element with the string (<p class="font-[300]">Any available Pool will appear here</p>) and the search only matches once with the string that appears in the script JSON.
I've tried delaying the getPageSource() function, since I thought the page wasn't being rendered fast enough, but that hasn't worked.
I can clearly see the string on the page, but it's nowhere to be found in the page source (except in the script json) so I'm very confused.
EDIT: I found out the getPageSource() function only returns the source of the last loaded page, and not the page modified by Javascript (source).  It seems I need to somehow update the page before getting its source but I'm not sure how to do that.
EDIT 2: As suggested by @NickSlash, I tried used xpath to find the string along with driver.wait()
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//p[text()='Any available Pool will appear here']")), 10000, "Not found", 500);

The string never does appear however.

the source is static, the webdriver gives you access to the live document so why bother with it? driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[text()='Any available Pool will appear here'])) (i have no way to test this, its just an example of what might work)

@NickSlash - I tried this and it hasn't worked. I get the error
NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//p[text()='Any available Pool will appear here']"}

If that element isn't found then that is the expected result? That element probably gets removed if a pool is available so not found. Without seeing the live html I can't offer any further help.

The pool isn't available. every time I run the program, the Chrome window opens up and shows that exact screenshot I posted, the string is there on the page, I just have no way of accessing it through selenium.
Is there any way that I could maybe contact you so I can offer more details?

Before Using Selenium, try to do it manually in Chrome using DevTools. (inspect the document, open the JS console and try stuff to manipulate the document)

Thank you so much for the suggestion! i was able to use return document.body.innerText; on the console to get the text displayed on the page. I used this in my Selenium script like this doc = await driver.executeScript('return document.body.innerText;'); and now I'm able to check if the string is present or not.
Again, your suggestion was a huge help and I am very grateful.

Thanks to @NickSlash, I have found a solution to my problem.
using the document.body.innerText; command in the JavaScript console provided in my browser returns the text document being displayed on the page.
I can execute this command through my Selenium script like this.
doc = driver.executeScript('return document.body.innerText;');
if (doc.search("Any available Pool will appear here") === -1) {
    console.log("not found");
} else {
    console.log("found");
}

to check if the string exists, and it works like a charm!
